# Integrate Azure Logic App with On Premises SMTP Relay for sending email

Tags: azure, smtp, azure-logic-apps

One of the actions in our Azure Logic App workflow is to notify the support group when there is an error in processing the rules.

We plan to integrate SMTP Relay which is running in on-Premise for this email notification requirement.

How to integrate that SMTP Relay with Logic App action for sending email for this use case?

Comment: VeeAar - Are you able to access any other on-premise server from your Azure vnet. Could you elaborate a bit on your Azure netfwork configuration. Does any of your Azure logic app today talk to any of your on-premise services/servers that are not publicly exposed.

Comment: @Rohan - This is the first time we are working on Logic App to connect with on-prem services (in this case, its SMTP Relay). But currently we have a PowerBI solution in Azure which connects to on-prem database via gateway.